# Multiprocessing with classes / Returning List - Python

Tags: python, list, class, return, multiprocessing

I'm trying to parallelize a code that I made to generate some images randomly (for an specific problem that I working on). As I use classes and I found that is not straightforward to multiprocess methods, I looked for some alternatives and found this approach:

```
#https://gist.github.com/fiatmoney/1086393
#MultiprocessingMethods.py

def _pickle_method(method):
    func_name = method.im_func.__name__
    obj = method.im_self
    cls = method.im_class
    if func_name.startswith('__') and not func_name.endswith('__'): #deal with mangled names
        cls_name = cls.__name__.lstrip('_')
        func_name = '_' + cls_name + func_name
    return _unpickle_method, (func_name, obj, cls)


def _unpickle_method(func_name, obj, cls):
    for cls in cls.__mro__:
        try:
            func = cls.__dict__[func_name]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            break
    return func.__get__(obj, cls)
```

So, I applied this to my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from PIL import Image

import MultiprocessingMethods as Mp
import Utils

import random
import pylab as plt  
import copy_reg
import types

copy_reg.pickle(types.MethodType, Mp._pickle_method, Mp._unpickle_method)

class ImageData(object):

    def __init__(self, width, height, range_min=-1, range_max=1):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        #The values range each pixel can assume
        self.range_min = range_min
        self.range_max = range_max
        self.data = []
        for i in range(width):
            self.data.append([0] * height)

    def generate_heat_map_image(self, name):
        """
        Generate a heat map of the image
        :param name: the name of the file
        """
        #self.normalize_image_data()
        plt.figure()
        fig = plt.imshow(self.data, extent=[-1, 1, -1, 1])
        plt.colorbar(fig)
        plt.savefig(name+".png")
        plt.close()

    def shepard_interpolation(self, seeds=10):
        print type (self.data)
        #Code omitted 'cause it doesn't effect the problem 
        return self.data


if __name__ == '__main__':   
    x = [ImageData(50, 50), ImageData(50, 50)]
    p = Pool()
    outputs = p.map(ImageData.shepard_interpolation,x)

    #A [[[ ]]]
    print outputs
    for i in range(len(outputs)):
        # A [[ ]]
        print outputs[i]
        outputs[i].generate_heat_map_image("ImagesOutput/Entries/Entry"+str(i))
```

Now I could parallelized my process, but I get as output an array of arrays and I don't know why. Before this, I always got an array of ImageData, and I could generate a heat map image with 
**matplotlib**. Does this kind of return have something to do with the multiprocessing? I guess so, 'cause I'm getting "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'generate_heat_map_image'", and the return should be a list of ImageData type, nor a list of lists. Can I return an array of ImageData?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I just had to put:

```
def shepard_interpolation(self, seeds=10):
    print type (self.data)
    #Code omitted 'cause it doesn't effect the problem 
    return self
```

Things that happens after 5 uninterruptible hours of programming.
Thank you, folks.

Answer (score 1):

The `ImageData` class identation is wrong, so your method doesn't actually belong to the class, even without multiprocessing ; here is the correct one :

```
class ImageData:
    def __init__(self, width, height, range_min=-1, range_max=1):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        #Which values each pixel can assume
        self.range_min = range_min
        self.range_max = range_max
        self.data = []
        for i in range(width):
           self.data.append([0] * height)

    def interpolate_points(self, seeds):
        points = []
        f = []
        for i in range(seeds):
            # Generate a cell position
            pos_x = random.randrange(self.width)
            pos_y = random.randrange(self.height)

            # Save the f(x,y) data
            x = Utils.translate_range(pos_x, 0, self.width, self.range_min, self.range_max)
            y = Utils.translate_range(pos_y, 0, self.height, self.range_min, self.range_max)
            z = Utils.function(x, y)
            points.append([x, y])

            f.append(z)
        for x in range(self.width):
            xt = (Utils.translate_range(x, 0, self.width, self.range_min, self.range_max))
            for y in range(self.height):
                yt = (Utils.translate_range(y, 0, self.height, self.range_min, self.range_max))
                self.data[x][y] = Utils.shepard_euclidian(points, f, [xt, yt], 3)

    # >>>> Note the identation change here!
    def generate_heat_map_image(self, name):
        """
        Generate a heat map of the image
        :param name: the name of the file
        """

        #self.normalize_image_data()
        plt.figure()
        fig = plt.imshow(self.data, extent=[-1, 1, -1, 1])
        plt.colorbar(fig)
        plt.savefig(name+".png")
        plt.close()
```

Comment: The indentation is ok in my code. This was a problem when I pasted it. I will edit.

Comment: What kind of error/exception do you get? Can you post a stack trace?

Comment: I found that is not straightforward to apply multiprocessing with Python. I found an alternative, but I still have problems. I will update my question. Thank you, @F.X.